@Transactional not rolling back in Spring Boot after RuntimeException
I am learning Spring Boot thoroughly and the last thing I am trying to learn is transaction management. I have read this article and now have a fairly good idea how it works.
But this is part of what makes learning Spring so frustrating, nothing just works, everything has so many hidden complexities,
If i put the @Transactional on the method, I expect it to roll back if an exception was thrown.
I have seen the many questions here and all address the same basic issue:
It must be a RuntimeException, it must not be calling a method from the same class, I have done all that, and for some reason this is not rolling back.
I am not sure if the Platform Transaction Manager needs to be explicitly configured and brought in to the tests.
I feel like i am missing something I should understand, but it's not clear.
Maybe everything is working as it should but i am not understanding why the rollback won't happen.
Here is a basic @Service class that uses a JpaRepository:
@Service
public class BasicTransactionExample {

    private TransactionARepository aRepository;

    private TransactionBRepository bRepository;

    public BasicTransactionExample(TransactionARepository aRepository, TransactionBRepository bRepository) {
        this.aRepository = aRepository;
        this.bRepository = bRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void startTransaction(boolean throwException) {
        TransactionA t1 = new TransactionA();
        t1.setName("TransactionA name");
        t1.setValue(10);
        aRepository.save(t1);

        if (throwException) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Deliberate exception thrown!");
        }

    }

}

I have imported the BasicTransactionExample service so I can autowire it, but it is still not working:
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Sql(scripts = "classpath:db/MiscSchema.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
@Import(BasicTransactionExample.class)
class BasicTransactionExampleTest {

    @Autowired
    private TransactionARepository aRepository;
    @Autowired
    private TransactionBRepository bRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BasicTransactionExample basicTransactionExample;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        
    }

    @Test
    void testOneWithoutException() {
        basicTransactionExample.startTransaction(false);
        List<TransactionA> aList = aRepository.findAll();
        assertEquals(1, aList.size()); // Okay
    }

    @Test
    void testThrows() {
        assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> basicTransactionExample.startTransaction(true));
        List<TransactionA> aList = aRepository.findAll();
        assertEquals(0, aList.size()); // Fails, count is 1, but expected 0
    }

I have looked at countless resources on the internet, but i can't find anything that tells me what I have missed.
I expect I will get downvoted for this, but I just can't figure it out

It doesn't rollback because there is no spring involved. You are doing new  BasicTransactionExample yourself. This doesn't allow Spring to create a proxy to drive the transaction, hence no rollback. Your code basically renders the @Transactional here useless and will use the @Transactional on the save method. This method finishes and is thus persisted before the exception will be thrown.

Yikes!!! I knew it was something silly i have done & don't understand. So I guess if I was doing a DataJpaTest, practically speaking I would need to configure this bean in the context, or is it pointless to do this test ? Similarly when I try JdbcTest, without jpa, does this mean, the bean that has the Transactional needs to be in the context ?

@DataJpaTest is intended for testing repositories not for testing services. If you want this bean to be added you can just do @Import(BasicTransactionExample.class) and then @AUtowired an instance into your test. But that is kind of abusing the @DataJpaTest.

Thank you for this, So if @DataJpaTest is just for repositories, and I am using the repository implementations in service like in this example, then are you suggesting that transactions should only be tested with SpringBootTest when the whole context is loaded ? If I wanted to test the whole data access functionality, and if transactions are an important part, how else would I do this ? the only other option I can think of would be to create a custom test slice I guess if this is abusing DataJpaTest,

If this type of test is pointless, then I can accept that, learn from it and only test transactions in SpringBootTest

I tried this, It still fails

As mentioned by M.Deinum, you should not be using the @DataJpaTest to test your service layer, instead you should define your test with @SpringBootTest (research it and possibly the difference between it and the JPA one). This will load your application context, including the repositories. The Transaction aspect is not directly linked to the repository layer itself, it depends on how you define your application, since you used it in your service method you defined that whatever happens in that method should be under a single transaction (there are exceptions but it is another talk).
